# Is it possible for on-premise application to push(publish) messages directly to AWS Eventbridge /EventBus?

Tags: amazon-web-services, integration, messaging

Say you have a bunch of on premise applications (that are your potential publishers).. can we have them (sitting in some private network), publish message on to an AWS eventBus/eventBridge, so that the target subscribers can take it forward from there... Does hybrid AWS help here?
If so, can you share some links on achieving the same

Answer (score 0):

That should be very straight forward - you can use the put events endpoint of any AWS SDK for EventBridge.

You'll need an IAM user with which to call the API via access key/secret key.

From a networking perspective, you'll need to be able to hit the AWS API endpoints.

Here's the method to use in Python.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#EventBridge.Client.put_events